# Subclasses and JSF EL

Tags: jsf, inheritance, el

I have a class and subclasses who extends that. Like this:

```
 @Table
    @Entity
    class Cat{



    class DomesticCat extends Cat{
       String litterBox;

    //getter and setters


    }

    class TigerCat extends Cat{
       String huntingStyle;

    //getter and setters
    }


}
```

i have a `List<Cat> cats` in my controller bean.
i filled it like

```
cats.add(new DomesticCat());
cats.add(new TigerCat());
```

Here i want to write sth like this in my xhtml page

```
<ui:repeat var="cat" value="#{controller.cats}">
<outputText rendered="tried some control here, did not work" value="cat.litterBox"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

i am getting "Property not found exception".

is it possible?

**EDIT**

**Wrong question sorry,
what do you advise me to do to using extending subclasses and JSF together.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF and expression language: Bind property only when it exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619183/jsf-and-expression-language-bind-property-only-when-it-exists)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613193/javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-when-submitting-uirepeat-with-conditionally/

Answer (score 1):

When the Expression Language tries to resolve the `litterBox` property on an instance of `TigerCat` it will throw an exception.

See the documentation for `BeanELResolver` in the [EL specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245):

> `getValue(ELContext, Object, Object)`
>
> *other documentation elided...*
>
> **If the property is not found or is not readable, a PropertyNotFoundException is thrown.**

This is the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible and it's the correct behavior.

How would the EL parser go about resolving `litterBox` on 'TigerCat'? If both a TigerCat and DomesticCat are added to the list `cats`, an exception will thrown when it hits your TigerCat.

If you put a dog in the list with the cats and put value="dog.bark" wouldn't you expect the same behavior?