# Parent attribute #{cc.parent.attrs.attrName}: exist or not?

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I use `#{cc.parent.attrs.nameAttr}` for referring to attribute of parent component. But the parent may not contain it. How do I know this?

Comment: would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619183/jsf-and-expression-language-bind-property-only-when-it-exists

Comment: unfortunately I didn't find the answer there..